# COPY INTO fails when one of the csv columns has quotes as part of the data

Tags: csv, azure-synapse

I have a CSV file with a column contains `"` as part of the data
The file is initially copied in ASF from SFTP location to ADLS
in the copy activity I tried adding quotes as the Quote character so my data looks like (this is just an example, the actual file is bigger)

ID ^ Name

"1" ^ "Galaxy 7" "

what breaking the Azure Synapse COPY INTO command is the inches sign (") next to  Galaxy 7

I even tried adding \ as an escape character in the data source that outputs the CSV into adls  but did not help

always getting same error

> Bulk load failed due to invalid column value in CSV data file
> /dev/switchingdb/avi_1.txt in row 2, column 21.

copy into command

```
COPY INTO stg.cdm_stg_Switching_DB FROM 'https://prdacrdatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/adf/dev/switchingdb/avi_1.txt'
                WITH (
                        FILE_TYPE = 'CSV'
                    --  ,COMPRESSION = 'gzip'
                        ,FIELDQUOTE ='"'
                        ,FIRSTROW =2
                        ,FIELDTERMINATOR ='^'
                        ,CREDENTIAL = (IDENTITY = 'Managed Identity')
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an escape character in the COPY INTO command.

```
COPY INTO stg.cdm_stg_Switching_DB FROM 'https://prdacrdatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/adf/dev/switchingdb/avi_1.txt'
    WITH (
        FILE_TYPE = 'CSV',
        FIELDQUOTE = '"',
        ESCAPE = '\\',
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '^',
        CREDENTIAL = (IDENTITY = 'Managed Identity')
    )
```

It will tell the COPY to treat the backslash character (`\`) as an escape character. By using double backslashes (`\\`), you can include a literal double quote (`"`) within a field without it being interpreted as the closing quote.